# C++ std::tuple<Ts...> to std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>>

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

Given a variadic template, I would like to define an object that would be a tuple of vector of each type in the variadic template.

Something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class C {    
   std::tuple<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>,...,std::vector<Tn>> vectors;
};
```

It does not have to be one data member, I mean, if it is possible to accomplish this using more auxiliary types or objects, that would not be a problem.

I tried a combination of `std::make_index_sequence` with `std::tuple`, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
class C {    
   std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> vectors;
};
```

This expands the pattern (`std::vector<Ts>`) for each type in the pack (resulting in your desired `std::tuple<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>,...,std::vector<Tn>>`)

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to use a class here, you can make use of a simple type-alias template:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using VectorTuple = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
```